# Compiler complains 'QTransform::QTransform(bool)' is private when using public bool, why?

Tags: c++, qt

The first block of the qt class is:

```
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QTransform
{
public:
    enum TransformationType {
        TxNone      = 0x00,
        TxTranslate = 0x01,
        TxScale     = 0x02,
        TxRotate    = 0x04,
        TxShear     = 0x08,
        TxProject   = 0x10
    };
```

So obvisiously its not private.

When I now try to compile my programm the compiler complains about this line:

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
item = scene.itemAt(50, 50, QTransform::TxNone);
```

It gives me:

> error: 'QTransform::QTransform(bool)' is private
>
> ```
> inline QTransform(bool)
>        ^
> ```

followed by:

> error: within this context
>
> ```
>  item = scene.itemAt(50,50,QTransform::TxNone);
>                                              ^
> ```

But I have no clue what makes the compiler assume `QTransform::TxNone` is an atempt to call the QTransform method.

So what am I doing wrong?
And how to make clear I'm not refering to a method but the public enum of the class as seen in the first snippet I posted?

Comment: is that `QTransform` a subclass of `QObject` or `QWidget`?

Comment: You did not show the definition of `itemAt`. But the error message indicates that the third parameter is actually meant to be a `QTransform` object, not an enum instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the problem:

```
QGraphicsItem * QGraphicsScene::itemAt(qreal x, qreal y, const QTransform & deviceTransform) cons
```

it accepts a `QTransform` object ...

```
QTransform()
QTransform(qreal m11, qreal m12, qreal m13, qreal m21, qreal m22, qreal m23, qreal m31, qreal m32, qreal m33 = 1.0)
QTransform(qreal m11, qreal m12, qreal m21, qreal m22, qreal dx, qreal dy)
QTransform(const QMatrix & matrix)
```

but there is no contructor that could convert from your used enum to the transformation object

Comment: Gah, beat me to it. There is a constructor that can convert from enum to `QTransform`, which is the `private QTransform(bool)`, which explains the error message.

Comment: `enum` is basically an `int` and you can implicit convert `int` to `bool`. it is misleading but in the documentation there is no mention of a ctor that would accept the `QTransform::TransformationType`